# Trouble Passing Parameter from UiAlertAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, increment

I have a custom NSObject called *MapLayer*, and an NSMuttableArray of MapLayers, creatively titled *layersMutableArray*.  On a button press, I put up a *UIAlertController*.  I populate this alert with a list of my MapLayers, as so:

```
    __block NSInteger *n;
    n = 0;
    for (MapLayer *m in layersMutableArray) {
        UIAlertAction *newAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:m.sLayerName style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
            MapLayer *ml = layersMutableArray[(int)n];
            curLayer = ml;
            [self loadSpecificLayer];
            n++;
        }];
        [layerSelectionAlertView addAction:newAction];
    }
```

Now, all this works fine.  My AlertView shows up with all the right stuff in it.

Here's the issue: when I click a "layer" (a UIAlertAction), and I call my loadSpecficLayer method, it always just reloads my first layer.  I think I am doing something incorrectly with the memory allocation and my int (creatively titled n), such that it's always being remembered as 0 and not incrementing, but I'm not sure.  I've tried various types of numbers (NSInteger, int), casting, and other tricks.  Any help much appreciated!

Comment: `n` isn't being incremented until the Block _runs_. You need to move that outside the Block and into the body of the loop.

Comment: True Josh, but I think rmaddy identified the bigger issue, which was my ridiculous failure to notice that I already have my layer from my iteration so I don't need to use any integer to get it again hahaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the use of `n`. It's not needed. Simply do:

```
for (MapLayer *m in layersMutableArray) {
    UIAlertAction *newAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:m.sLayerName style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        curLayer = m;
        [self loadSpecificLayer];
    }];
    [layerSelectionAlertView addAction:newAction];
}
```

Or, move the increment of `n` to outside of the block.